# Get computers last logon times

Tags: powershell

Could You point me how to properly complete my task? And why close dates get quite different ticks?
Sorry for long post but I want to explain it clearly.

I want to obtain computers last logon times (from two domain controllers) and get those which didn't logged since 1st May 2022.
I assign to a $KolStacji23 variable a collection of computers object from the 1st DC with lastLogon and lastLogontimeStamp attributes and to a $KolStacji71 variable collection from the 2nd DC. Then I compare values of those attributes.

```
$Nieaktywne = ((Get-Date).AddDays(- 120)).Ticks
    foreach ($Stacja23 in $KolStacji23) {
        foreach ($Stacja71 in $KolStacji71) {
            if ($Stacja23.Name -eq $Stacja71.Name) {
                if ((($($Stacja23.LastLogon) -lt $Nieaktywne) -and ($($Stacja71.LastLogon) -lt $Nieaktywne) -and ($($Stacja23.lastLogontimeStamp) -lt $Nieaktywne)) -and ($Stacja23.whenCreated -lt $Nieaktywne)) {
                    $Stacja23.Name
                    if ($Stacja23.lastLogontimeStamp -gt $Stacja23.LastLogon) {
                        $Stacja23.LastLogon = $Stacja23.lastLogontimeStamp
                    }
                    if ($Stacja71.LastLogon -gt $Stacja23.LastLogon) {
                        $Stacja23.LastLogon = $Stacja71.LastLogon                       }
                    $Stacja23 | Select-Object Name, @{ N = 'lokalizacja'; E = { ($($_.CanonicalName)).split("/")[-3] } }, whenCreated, @{ N = 'LastLogon'; E = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon) } }, operatingSystem, Description | Export-Csv -Path $PlikListy -Delimiter ';' -Force -NoClobber -Encoding UTF8 -Append -NoTypeInformation
                }
                Break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it looks strange from the start. My OS is Polish, so "kwietnia" means April, "sierpnia" means August, "września" means September.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Date
czwartek, 1 września 2022 13:49:57

PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-Date).AddDays(- 124)
sobota, 30 kwietnia 2022 13:50:06

PS C:\Windows\system32> ((Get-Date).AddDays(- 124)).Ticks
637869234152030929
```

At the same time computer account attributes are as below.

```
([DateTime]::FromFileTime($Stacja23.LastLogon))
środa, 22 września 2021 15:48:59

$Stacja23.LastLogon
132767921394245654

[DateTime]::FromFileTime($Stacja23.LastLogontimeStamp)
poniedziałek, 22 sierpnia 2022 19:05:11

$Stacja23.LastLogontimeStamp
133056615112570357
```

Ticks are much smaller in these case. If I try to revert them to "normal" date format with [datetime] results are different - they are from the ancient times (1600 years ago).

```
$Stacja23.LastLogontimeStamp
133056615112570357

[datetime]$Stacja23.LastLogon
środa, 22 września 0421 13:48:59

[datetime]$Stacja23.LastLogontimeStamp
poniedziałek, 22 sierpnia 0422 17:05:11
```

Are computer account attributes calculated different way? How to proceed them correctly - add ticks for 1600 years (how much it would be)?

Comment: FileTime and DateTime are two wildly different data structures with different encoding schemes, you can't compare ticks and filetime offsets. You want `$Nieaktywne = [DateTime]::ToFileTime((Get-Date).AddDays(- 120))` instead of DateTime Ticks

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. It doesn't work. "Method invocation failed because [System.DateTime] does not contain a method named 'ToFileTime'."

Comment: My bad, it's an instance method: `$Nieaktywne = (Get-Date).AddDays(- 120).ToFileTime()`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. Thank You again. You helped me for the second time.